# Total number of ways to paint great rhombicosadodecahedron with n colors

Tags: polyhedra

Is there a general formula for the total number of ways to paint a great rhombicosadodecahedron using n colors? What about for the total number of unique ways?

Comment: Wow. What a question! Might be a good idea to put any preliminary work or thoughts of yours here.

Comment: Preliminary thoughts? Well I'd start off by considering all of the symmetries and in fact, I have been considering all of the symmetries - but a general formula does not come to mind.

Comment: There is. It's the chromatic polynomial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial . But I don't know how to calculate it.